# Adding programs to default list

Tags: windows-vista, file-association

Can Outlook email be added into the list of default programs in windows vista? In 'Set Default Programs'  there are only 2 programs listed, which are Firefox & Picasa Photo Viewer.  Can other programs be added?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is possible.

1. Click the **Start** button, then click the **Default Programs** item. 
   [image]
2. Then, **Set Program Access and Computer Defaults**
   [image]
3. Click **Custom**
   [image]
4. Scroll down and find "**Choose a default e-mail prorgam**", then select the radio box next to "Outlook"
   [image]

---

Source: [Windows - Setting the Default Mail Program](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=170)

Comment: the choices I have are - Use my current e-mail program                        Windows Mail           or   Windows Live Mail          Is it possible to add Microsoft Office Outlook  to this list?

Comment: Outloook _should_ be there. That screenshot is from Vista as well. Maybe older versions of outlook don't display for some reason.